# While Loop in php not working properly to fetch content using file_get_contents

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I am fetching pagination urls list from another website using file_get_contents but the while loop won't work, it fetches data of the first url and thats it won't work on the second url of the array fetched from my database of urls.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
$crawl_query = "SELECT url from list LIMIT 10"; 
$crawl_url = mysqli_query($con, $crawl_query);
$rows = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($crawl_url))
{
    $pages = $rows['url'];
    $html = file_get_contents($pages);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $links = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'pages')]");
    $array1= array();


    foreach ($links as $link){
        $array1[] = $link;
        $length[] = $array1[0]->getElementsByTagName('a');
        $final_length = $length[0]->length -1;

        for($i=1; $i<=$final_length; $i++ )
        {
            if($i==1)
            {
            echo rtrim($pages, ".html").trim($i, "1");
            echo "<br/>";
            }
            else
            {
            echo rtrim($pages, ".html")."_".trim($i, "1");
            echo "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All I get is

```
example.com/content/new
example.com/content/new2
example.com/content/new3
```

which is the result of first url in my database. That url has 3 pages in it's pagination but I can't get the loop to work on second url from mydb.

Comment: _All I get is...._ Maybe there are only 3 records. What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes that is the expected result it's ok but the process won't restart with second url in the array fetched in while loop.

Comment: Have you var_dump'ed $rows['url'] to see what is in there??

Comment: @B001 it says _string(59) "https://www.example.com/content/new.html"_